# Location of Event Studio objects on the Cognos Server

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

I'm looking for the path to Event Studio saved objects, on the Cognos 10 server.

For example this is <strike>a report</strike> sth I've made with Event Studio. I assume this object is saved as a file somewhere on the Cognos Server. Where (in which folder) can I find this object?

[image]

---

**Edit:** I need to create a lot of event studio files (I don't know what are these files called. I'm referring to the file in the photo) that differ only on the prompt value and the location they get exported. Doing this from the web interface takes a long time. Need to copy the object, rename it, change the prompt values and export path, and this requires a lot of clicks.
I was assuming these objects get saved as files on the Server. So I though if I can access one of these files on the server and - if possible - edit it by changing the prompt values and the export path (which are mentioned somewhere in the file), and save it as a new file, then it saves me a lot of time.

Based on the comments, it seems my assumption was wrong and these objects are not stored as files on the server.
So the question is, how can I create all these objects in a more efficient way (instead of using the web interface to change the prompt values and the export path, and save as new objects)?

Comment: Event Studio is not used to create reports.

Answer (score 2):

Event Studio Agents are stored in the Content Store database.

Comment: What do yo mean "as a file"? Files are stored in the file system. As Dougp answered, the Event Studio objects only exist in the Content Store, which is stored in a relational database.

Comment: This is a  x-y problem.  What is it which you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Reports (report specs) are also stored in the Content Store database.

Comment: @Tripanosomagambiense Thanks for the comments. I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

If  you don't want to use the web user interface then you have two options:

1. Use the Cognos SDK
2. Use a third party tool

The first option is complex and time-consuming. For the second option I have used a free tool called MotioPI. I have used it to create hundreds of report views based on a set of reports with different prompt values. I guess you can do the same with Event Studio agents. It was also a time consuming and boring task, but it was quicker than with the web interface.